# In python exclude folders which start with underscore or more than six characters long

Tags: python, list-comprehension, directory-walk

I want to store all the folder names except the folders which start with underscore (_) or have more than 6 characters.To get the list, i use this code

```
folders = [name for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)]
```

What change do i need to make to get the desired output.

Comment: Do you need the recursive `os.walk` or not?

Comment: i used @dr-jimbob solution
'folders = [name for name in os.listdir(".") 
           if os.path.isdir(name) and name[0] != '_' and len(name) <= 6]'

Comment: Do you mean you don't need recursive then? You should edit the question to say, because your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the simplest way is to extend the if clause of your list comprehension to contain two more clauses:

```
folders = [name for name in os.listdir(".") 
           if os.path.isdir(name) and name[0] != '_' and len(name) <= 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use **os.walk**. This would traverse the entire directory tree from the top level directory you specify.

```
import os
from os.path import join
all_dirs  = []

for root,dirs,filenames in os.walk('/dir/path'):
    x = [join(root,d) for d in dirs if not d.startswith('_') and len(d)>6]
    all_dirs.extend(x)
print all_dirs # list of all directories matching the criteria
```

Comment: i did not try with os.walk. I'll give this a try

Comment: Bug: exclude-condition `not d.startswith('_') and len(d)>6` should be '<=6'. `not` is taking precedence over `and`. Use parens for clarity:

Comment: @smci why so ? OP wants * folders that doesn't start with _ and * folders that have length >6 . Boolean NOT has a higher precedence over boolean AND, so the above conditional would be fine. Though adding parentheses to disambiguate would have been better.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension might be too unwieldy for this, so I have expanded it to make it clear what the conditions are:

```
folders = []

for name in os.listdir('.'):
   if os.path.isdir(name):
      dirname = os.path.basename(name)
      if not (dirname.startswith('_') or len(dirname) > 6):
         folders.append(name)
```